# Implementing a European Option class

Tags: c++, class, oop, attributes

I need implement the class **Option_Pricer** that encapsulates all the functions relevant to price both call and put options. The teacher is giving me a code listing (.cpp file) that I have to turn into a class. All the functions that I used in my class are therefore coming from the teacher. I simply have to implement them as a class.

Here is what I have done so far: I have split the code into two different files. One is called option_pricer.hpp and is used as an header for the main file option_pricer.cpp.

```
//option_pricer.hpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

class Option_Pricer {
    
private:
    
    void init();
    
public:
    
    double S;
    double K;
    double r;
    double v;
    double T;
    double x;
    double j;

 public:
    //Constructors
    call_price();
    put_price();
    norm_pdf();
    norm_cdf();
    d_j() const;

// Assignment operator
call_price& operator = (const call_price& call);
put_price& operator = (const put_price& put);
    
};
```

Here is the main file:

```
//option_pricer.cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include "option_pricer.hpp"


double Option_Pricer::norm_pdf(const double& x) const {
    return (1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*x*x); 
}

double Option_Pricer::norm_cdf(const double& x) const {
    double k = 1.0/(1.0 + 0.2316419*x);
    double k_sum = k*(0.319381530 + k*(-0.356563782 + k*(1.781477937 + k*(-1.821255978 + 1.330274429*k))));
    
    if (x >= 0.0) {
        return (1.0 -(1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*x*x) * k_sum);
                } 
    else {
        return 1.0 - norm_cdf(-x);
                } 
}

double Option_Pricer::d_j(const int& j, const double& S, const double& K, const double& r, const double& v, const double& T) const {
    return (log(S/K) + (r + (pow(-1,j 1))*0.5*v*v)*T)/(v*(pow(T,0.5)));
}

double Option_Pricer::call_price(const double& S, const double& K, const double& r, const double& v, const double& T) const {
    return S * norm_cdf(d_j(1, S, K, r, v, T))-K*exp(-r*T) * norm_cdf(d_j(2, S, K, r, v, T));
}
    
double Option_Pricer::put_price(const double& S, const double& K, const double& r, const double& v, const double& T) const {
      return -S*norm_cdf(-d_j(1, S, K, r, v, T))+K*exp(-r*T) * norm_cdf(-d_j(2, S, K, r, v, T)); 
    
}
    

int main() {
    
Option_Pricer p;
   p.S = 100.0;
   p.K = 100.0;
   p.r = 0.05;
   p.v = 0.2;
   p.T = 1.0;
double call_price = p.call_price();
double call_put = p.put_price();

 
// Finally we output the parameters and prices 
std::cout << "Underlying: " << p.S << std::endl;
std::cout << "Strike: " << p.K << std::endl;
std::cout << "Risk-Free Rate: " << p.r << std::endl;
std::cout << "Volatility: "<< p.v << std::endl;
std::cout << "Maturity: " << p.T << std::endl;
std::cout << "Call price: " << call_price << std::endl;
std::cout << "Put price: " << call_put << std::endl;

return 0; 
    
}
```

However, as you can guess, my code isn't compiling really well. My most common error is the following:

> option_pricer.cpp:7:8: error: no declaration matches ‘double Option_Pricer::norm_pdf(const double&) const’
> 7 | double Option_Pricer::norm_pdf(const double& x) const {
> |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

I don't understand how I should call the norm_pdf from outside of the header (same question for norm_cdf and d_j).

I'm fairly new to C++ (was using Python before) and therefore don't understand yet how am I supposed to access the variables (S, K,...) from outside of my class.

Help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I have much trouble understanding what you are asking. Is all that code pertaining?

Comment: Are you learning C++ from a good book?  I ask this, since no good book would show initializing non-static member variables this way (which is why you are probably getting compiler errors).  What does your book say about default constructors, constructors in general, and initializing member variables?  Or are you doing the wrong thing by trying to leverage your Python knowledge into C++?

Comment: A question about compiler errors that does not reproduce the full text of the compiler errors is on a one-way trip to oblivion. Add the compiler errors. Better still, back up your code and produce a [mre] that produces exactly one error message (note that this one error message can sometimes go on for pages). Often when you reduce the code to exactly enough to produce the error, the cause of the error becomes obvious.

Comment: `(1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))` -- Note that this is a constant.  You're probably incurring a performance hit by calling `pow`.  Just declare a `double` constant instead of having to call `pow`.

Comment: `//Constructors` is an incorrect comment. You have no constructors for your `Option_Pricer` class. And they are not below the comment.

Comment: @Jeffrey I updated my code to make it more clean, I'm trying to implement a class to price a European option call/put.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually, I'm only learning C++ from my course slides and exercises... I should definitely get my hands on one copy of a good book because I'm struggling so much with the basics.

Comment: @user4581301 I updated my code with one common error I had, it's about accessing my class variables.

Comment: Now that the code is somewhat different. Your declarations must match your implementations: `double Option_Pricer::norm_pdf(const double& x) const` is very different from `norm_pdf();` Also `norm_pdf();` has no return type and is not a constructor. A constructor must have the same name of class.

Comment: @drescherjm A quick practical question: when people make comments about my code, should I edit my OP or create a new message ? Thanks for your answer, actually I'm not sure what a constructor exactly is so I should look into that. Is norm_pdf necessarily a constructor?

Comment: In the Option_Pricer class a constructor would be `Option_Pricer() {};`

Comment: Normally if someone has answered you don't edit your code anymore especially if it makes their answer invalid. The main purpose of your question is to help future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make and understand the distinction between a class and an object.  Very simply, an object is a collection of values in memory, and a class is a description of those values and of code that will use data organized according to the class description.

So, since `Option_Pricer` is a class, it doesn't make sense to say `Option_Pricer.S = 100.0;` in your `main()` method.  You need to create an object of type `Option_Pricer`, and then fill that object's memory region with the values you want.  A common method for doing that - especially in your case where you are simply initializing the object with numeric data - is to create and use a constructor, although you could modify your `init()` method to take arguments and set values and that would be fine too.  You can even set the values one-by-one as you have done, since you made the values `public`, but you have to modify the object, not the class.

Ex.

```
int main()
{
   Option_Pricer p(100.0, 100.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
   double call_price = p.call_price();

   // or
   Option_Pricer p2;
   p2.init(100.0, 100.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
   double call_price2 = p2.call_price();

   // or, if you like typing or want the meaning of the numbers to be super clear
   Option_Pricer p3;
   p3.S = 100.0;
   p3.K = 100.0;
   p3.r = 0.05;
   p3.v = 0.2;
   p3.T = 1.0;

   // ...
```

This doesn't address everything that's wrong with your code, but I'd start by addressing the above.  I think the problems that others are pointing out will be easier to sort out once you get the concept of an object squared away.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I did what you advised and my code is already fixed in the OP. Still not compiling but it's much better!